# SSL Certificate Chain Incomplete

Tags: java, ssl, encryption, ssl-certificate, keytool

Can someone please explain what exactly the SSL Labs test's "This server's certificate chain is incomplete" means and how to fix it? Exact steps of what I did

1. Generate Let's Encrypt certificate via the Let's Encrypt client using the standalone module (./letsencrypt-auto --standalone)
2. This yielded 4 files: cert1.pem, chain1.pem, fullchain1.pem, privkey1.pem
3. Generate PKCS12 file to import the certificate:

> openssl pkcs12 -export -in cert1.pem -inkey privkey1.pem -out
>   cert_and_key.p12 -name certificate -CAfile fullchain1.pem -caname root

4. Create the keystore:

> keytool -importkeystore -deststorepass Pas5w0rd123 -destkeypass
>   Pas5w0rd123 -destkeystore cert.jks -srckeystore cert_and_key.p12
>   -srcstoretype PKCS12 -srcstorepass Pas5w0rd123 -alias cert
>
> keytool -import -trustcacerts -alias root -file chain1.pem -keystore
>   cert.jks

5. Now using the created cert.jks on a server and having it tested with SSL Labs, the SSL test reports this problem: "This server's certificate chain is incomplete.".

Thanks very much in advance for your answers!

Comment: Most likely means the root is not in SSL Labs trust package.  Do they include the Let's Encrypt root cert?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that in certificate chain is missing the certificate Let's Encrypt Authority X3.

Check that your pkcs12 really contains the private key, the public key and the certification chain. The best option is to use the GUI portecle (http://portecle.sourceforge.net/)

When creating the pkcs12 '-CAfile fullchain1.pem' should be '-certfile fullchain1.pem'.

Comment: Pedrofb, thanks for your response. 1) Yes, it does contain them - you can recreate the exact same jks file I have by following the steps above. 2) The same jks file is being used both as keystore and truststore by the server - if you're interested, it is a SparkJava server, securing it with spark.Spark.secure(keystore, password, null, null).

Comment: Seems all right... Is 'DST Root CA X3' also included in fullchain1.pem?

Comment: Yes, the certificate path according to SSL Labs is as follows: 1. Sent by server - my domain, 2. Extra download - Let's Encrypt Authority X3, 3. In trust store - DST Root CA X3 Self-signed

Comment: 'Extra download' is the output of SSLLabs??. It should be 'sent by server'

Comment: It seems that in certificate chain is missing the certificate Let's Encrypt Authority X3 . When creating the pkcs12 '-CAfile fullchain1.pem' should be '-certfile fullchain1.pem'. Please check with portecle you have the certificate 'Let's Encrypt Authority X3' in the jks

Comment: Thank you, the answer is correct now and it resolved the problem.